# How to pass type and id to laravel polymorphic relation

Tags: php, laravel

I have a navigation model that can have many items associated with it:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;
use JetBrains\PhpStorm\ArrayShape;
use Laravel\Scout\Searchable;

class Navigation extends Model
{
  use HasFactory;
  use Searchable;

  protected $guarded = [];

  public function navigation_items(): HasMany
  {
    return $this->hasMany(NavigationItem::class);
  }
}
```

The navigation item model looks like this

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphTo;

class NavigationItem extends Model
{
  use HasFactory;

  protected $guarded = [];

  public function navigation(): BelongsTo
  {
    return $this->belongsTo(Navigation::class);
  }

  public function navigatable(): MorphTo
  {
    return $this->morphTo();
  }
}
```

Now an item can either be of type `Page` or `Blog`, in this case the `Page` model looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphOne;
use JetBrains\PhpStorm\ArrayShape;
use Laravel\Scout\Searchable;

class Page extends Model
{
  protected $guarded = [];

  public function navigatable(): MorphOne
  {
    return $this->morphOne(NavigationItem::class, 'navigatable');
  }
}
```

When I try to save a navigation model and associate it with a item, the following error appears:

`SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'navigatable_type' doesn't have a default value`

I save the model like this:

```
    foreach ($this->selected as $id) {
      $this->navigation->navigation_items()->create([
        'navigation_id' => $this->navigation->id,
      ]);
```

Where `$this->selected` is the `navigation` id, it should automatically get the correct `navigatable_type` and `navigatable_id`, but this doesn't seem to be working.

passing in the `type` and `id` manually works, but this kinda defeats the point of a polymorphic relationship.

any ideas?

Comment: set default null to `navigatable_type` into database

Comment: It is invalid method to call create function through relation. If it's a relation you should refer to attach() methods. Can you please expand the explanation. On which model are you trying to create record

Comment: Also can you please include the migration regarding polymorphic relation.

Answer (score 0):

On NavigationItem model, since you defined polymorphic relation as 'navigatable' it is expected that NavigationItem model's table contains navigatable_type and navigatable_id. First please ensure this checks out.

Creating records through relation's base function is not a valid method. It is not clear what you are trying to achieve there but when you want to set relation there is two standard way of achieving it:

**1- Associate**

When a relation is defined as belongsTo, you may use associate() function. Like so:

```
$account = Account::find(10);
 
$user->account()->associate($account);
```

**2- Attach**

Attach is used when relation is defined belongsToMany (pivot). It allows you to attach multiple records to a model instance/record.

```
$user = User::find(1);
 
$user->roles()->attach($roleId);
```

So if you want to set a 'navigatable' to a Navigation instance, you may:

```
$somePageInstance=Page::find(55);
$nagivation->navigatable()->associate($somePageInstance)
$nagivation->save();//remember to save, otherwise it won't be
```

Comment: Hey, just for some clarification, the `Navigation` model can have many `NavigationItems`, these items can either be of type `Blog` or of type `Page`